# HTML custom tags (HTML functions)

Tags: html

Is it possible to create HTML functions like you can do with... I don't know... JS?

Could you do something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html version=5>
    <body>
      <function name="para" attr1="text">
        <p localName="para"></p>
        <script type="functionHTML/javaScript">
          function.data("attr1")includes = getLocalElementByName("para")
        </script>
      </function>
      <-para text="Hello World!"></-para>
    </body>
  </html>
```

This would come out on the webpage as:

Hello World!

Comment: I find it funny we've come full circle back to wanting XML on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in general HTML, no. However, there are specifications, centrally the [Custom Elements spec](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/), and [projects](http://webcomponents.org) build [around](http://polymer-project.org) it, which enable you to define and reuse your own HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create html functions, but the JS is here to create functions and manipulate the DOM, so you can do that whit JS (use jQuery, it's easier)